# Make Raspberry Pi to recognize usb0 as eth0

Tags: usb, ethernet

I have CAT.m1 device that connected by USB.

It connects Raspberry Pi to the network.

In Raspberry Pi it is perceived as 'usb0'.

It can get IP address, and works well.

But I wish Raspberry Pi perceive that as `eth0` not the `usb0`.

Is there any way to make it?

Comment: why? if it works, don't break it

Comment: [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479)

Comment: @JaromandaX because there's a program that works only when the network is perceived as Ethernet, but it doesn't work when it's perceived as usb. 
Browsing internet by browser is work, but that program dosen't work.

Comment: "perceived" .... is the "perception" mechanism the name of the interface?

Answer (score 3):

Network interface names can be managed by `systemd`, which provides you with a way to use names you like via [`.link`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html) files. E.g. you can create a file `/etc/systemd/network/10-internet.link`:

```
[Match]
MACAddress=01:23:45:67:89:ab

[Link]
Name=internet0
```

Using built-in kernel names such as `eth0` may lead to trouble, but you can try to reuse them nevertheless.