# Prevent eth1 from being created

Tags: networking, pi-4

On my raspberry pi I am plugging a USB to ethernet adapter which is automatically assigned to eth1 but I would prefer having it be eth2.

I tried to add a dummy interface by doing `ip link add eth1 type dummy`. If I do this by hand and plug my adapter after it works.

I wanted to do that on boot so I added dummy in /etc/modules and I tried adding `ip link add eth1 type dummy` in rc.local (it didn't work).

I tried doing it as indicated [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994669/why-does-ip-link-add-not-work-in-rc-local/994711) which didn't work either.

Comment: See if you can rename the interface using a [.link file](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113437/make-raspberry-pi-to-recognize-usb0-as-eth0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to name the wired interface to **eth2**. That is very easy with systemd-networkd using the MAC address. Just create this file and reboot:

```
rpi ~$ cat /etc/systemd/network/02-eth.link
[Match]
# example, use your MAC address
MACAddress=dc:a6:32:7f:38:46

[Link]
Name=eth2
```

Comment: I thought in raspberry pi 4 (and therefore raspbian stretch) networkd should not be used. Did I misunderstood something ?

Comment: @f222 There is nothing said about stretch.You use a Raspberry Pi 4B. That is only supported by Buster (and later versions when available). But anyway, **systemd** is the main init system since Jessie, the  predecessor of Stretch, and should be used instead of the deprecated and only emulated **SysV** init system. Renaming the interface this way, the `systemd-networkd.service` is not needed and must not run. Default **dhcpcd** networking is not affected.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way of doing it without using a dummy interface.

First I used raspi-config to enable **predictable network names**.

Then I created a file named /etc/udev/rules.d/10-network-device.rules.
In this file I put a line like `SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="mac_addr", NAME="interface_name"` for each ethernet interface I have.

This [post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51359/network-names-switch-on-raspberry-pi/51369#51369) made me find my answer.